# spring ThreadPoolTaskScheduler not run schedule with Instant

Tags: java, spring-boot

```java
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler s = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
s.initialize();
s.setPoolSize(1);
// Date date = DateUtils.parseDate("20190618 00:10:40", "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
s.schedule(() -> {
    System.out.println("a");
}, LocalDateTime.of(2019, 6, 18, 0, 10, 40).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

When is time, `a` is not print with `Instant` param, but show with `Date` param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [ConcurrentTaskScheduler.schedule()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ConcurrentTaskScheduler.html#schedule-java.lang.Runnable-java.util.Date-) method currently it does not support [Instant Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) so you have to try with Date or Trigger type only as second parameter to schedule method. So you can convert Instant to Date type and try like this :

```
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler s = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
s.initialize();
s.setPoolSize(1);
s.schedule(() -> System.out.println("a"), Date.from(LocalDateTime.of(2019, 6, 18, 0, 10, 40).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)));
```